# Vue3 dynamic render

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have a list of components and I want to set a config for them from outside,

For example:

```
 const myConfig = [
  {
    name: 'example',
    renderer: () => (<button @click="clickHanlder">Click me!</button>)
  },
  ...
 ];
```

And for my component I want to use `myConfig` as shown below:

```
  <template>
    <div class="example">
      <template v-for="(item, index) in myConfig" :key="index">
        My Button:
        <div class="example-2">{{ item.renderer() }}</div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Please pay attention that I don't want to use `slot`s

How I can do it?

Comment: are you using vite and script setup?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, I'm using script setup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve  that by using `h` render function as shown in the following example :

```html
<template v-for="(item, index) in myConfig" :key="index">
    My Button:
    <div class="example-2">
        <component :is="item.renderer" />
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">

import {  h } from 'vue';

const myConfig = [
  {
    name: 'example',
    renderer: h('button', {
  
      onClick:clickHanlder
      
    },'Click me !'),
  },

 ];

 function clickHanlder(){
    console.log('click btn');
 }

</script>
```